# How to extend curve on another curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to get something like this[image]

Now I'm struggling with extending this curly spring on a circle
[image]

When I try to use array and curve modifiers it doesn't work the way I want. 
[image]

For example, if I use fixed count with array modifier it works better, but the problem is that the final mesh is divided into independent parts.[image]

I guess, if I was able to modify(increase its length) this curly spring after its creation it would be much easier to do. Is there a way to do it somehow?

These both object is periodic by themselves. [image]
And if I use "Array" and "Curve" modifiers I get something that is not periodic
[image][image]

Should I manually make it as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the latest release of 2.80 beta.

For one thing, your original curve is not periodic--this means that if you try to link them end-to-end, the ends aren't going to match up. I would create a new curly object so that it will connect end-to-end with itself **without having to perform additional rotations**.

After this is done, make sure that the origins for the curly and and path are centered to geometric means and that their rotations and scale transformations have been applied.

Apply an array modifier to the curly object. choose "Fit Curve" as the "Fit Type:" and select the path object as the "Curve:".

Next apply the curve modifier and select the same path as the curve you are fitting to.

Using the X Axis as the "Deformation Axis:" tends to work best for the curve modifier but experiment with other axes if the curly's aren't arranged end-to-end. Here's something you might not have tried that I needed to do (although probably not since your path is closed): *You can move and rotate the curly object to fine-tune its position on the path*. I had to do this when I made these balusters follow a path that was curved like the banister:

[image]

Turn on "Merge" in the array modifier. Keeping the "Relative Offset:" value at "1.00" should string the curly end-to-end but you can adjust it if you have to. If you are close but the ends don't meet up, convert the whole thing to a mesh under the Object -> Convert To menu and move the vertices manually.

Comment if you have additional problems or questions.

Don't overthink "periodic", we are just talking about a repeating pattern. Here is a piece of the sin(x) wave function that repeats, for example:

[image]
Any piece of this function that is this long will repeat end-to-end.

**HOW TO CREATE PERIODIC CURVE THE EASY WAY:**

1) Create a Path object (Nurbs path or Bezier, doesn't matter, just make sure it is straight). Rotate the object so that it is oriented parallel to the z axis. Offset it from the z axis by 1 unit and move the object's origin to the world origin, as shown:

[image]

I decided to scale the path in the z-direction by half (personal choice):

[image]

Now add a SimpleDeform modifier. Make sure the option is set to Twist, the axis is set to X and the angle is set to 360 degrees (which is a complete revolution). Now your path is periodic.

[image]

Top view:

[image]

yet another view:

[image]

Now you can give the curve some bevel depth and convert it to a mesh (Object -> Convert To).

Comment: I don't really get how to create the curve and check if it is periodic or not

Comment: Updated post with instructions for creating a simple, periodic helix

Comment: I don't know how to add pictures in the comment section, that's why I edited post. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yep, I had that issue too, that's why I said give the curve some geometry by increasing the object's Bevel -> Depth parameter and then converting it to a mesh in from the Object -> Convert To menu.

Comment: Can you please have a look at edited post again?

Comment: Once you have the mesh, create the circle path object that you want the mesh to be repeated along. You will probably have to move the mesh onto the circle (you will definitely have to rotate it). Make sure both objects' origins are at the center of the circle. Now apply the array and curve modifiers to the mesh, using the circle as the path.

Comment: Look at this recent post for an example of curving bricks around a circle to make a well, it is similar to what you need to do:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139893/laying-curved-bricks-in-a-circle