# Laying curved bricks in a circle

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I want to recreate the brick layout in the well image below. Specifically, I want my bricks to perfectly mate end-to-end (in the image below, the bricks appear to be uniform size, each 1/8th the circumference of the well). I have attempted this in [my blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19CXBOu7QugX6lwco8r_eck_RZH1619GN/view?usp=sharing) by creating the curved bricks using an array and curve modifier, and then repeating the pieces using an array modifier and rotating about an empty. My pieces are not uniformly separated and overlap in one spot (see the .blend file or the images below). Is there a way to achieve what i'm after using modifiers and Blender functions without perfectly measuring out the size of my pieces manually?

**Reference image**

[image]

**A single one of my pieces**
[image]

**My pieces laid out in a circle, red circling the overlap of two pieces**
[image]

**Edit**

I tried using BlendExchange to upload the file but the page kept giving an upload error. [I have resorted to uploading to Google Drive instead.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19CXBOu7QugX6lwco8r_eck_RZH1619GN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: blend-exchange is a little confusing at first. Copy the URL from this question  into the URL field, then agree to the terms, then drag and drop your file into the box, then hit the upload button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're complicating the operation, the 2 most basic ways to do it is with a **Simple Deform** modifier or with a **Curve** modifier.

With a **Simple Deform** modifier (easiest in my opinion):

- Create your brick.
- Give it an *Array* modifier with the count of brick you want, enable *Merge* and *First Last*.
- Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier, choose the *Bend* mode, and an angle of 360°.
- Your well will automatically be 8 bricks / 360°.
- If you don't want the bricks to stick to each others, increase the *Array Relative Offset* value a bit and reduce the *Simple Deform Angle* (to adjust the first and last bricks).

With a **Curve** modifier:

- Create your brick.
- Create a curve. Put its origin somewhere on its circumference, put the brick at the same position as this point.
- Give your brick an *Array* modifier with the count of brick you want, enable *Merge* and *First Last*.
- Give it a *Curve* modifier. You will need to adjust the curve size to make the first and last brick stick to each other. When you scale, use <kbd>shift</kbd> to make it more precise.
- If you don't want the bricks to stick to each others, increase the *Array Relative Offset* value a bit and scale the curve.

[image]

Comment: Starting with a circle and extruding/subdividing that would be even more easier. It's even possible to create bricks with uneven sizes, like real medieval wells are built.

Comment: I don't know if it would have been easier, plus I think you are more free with Simple Deform, because you can come back to the original brick to edit it, etc...then at the end if you want uneven bricks you can apply the modifiers then work each one

Comment: Well... create one brick, delete the rest, add an Empty, add an Array modifier - Boom! Same Freedom.

Comment: ah you mean create one brick from an extruded circle? Not sure it will save a lot of time... + your prisoner of your brick shape